# Play the audio each time the button is pressed - flutter

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, audio, just-audio

What happens with my code is that, when I click the button for the first time, the audio plays but if I click it again, the audio does not play. What is the problem here? I want to play the audio file every time I click the button. Here is my code-

```
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late AudioPlayer player;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    player = AudioPlayer();
  }

  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  await player.setAsset('assets/Audios/win.wav');
                  player.play();
                },
                child: const Text('Win'),
              ),
              
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am building this application in Flutter framework for Windows platform. 'just_audio' dependency is added in the pubspec.yaml file and the audio file is stored under assets/Audios directory.

Comment: You are violating the rules of audio player. Set the source in initState and stop the player before playing it again in onPress button event.

Comment: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/19899190/103147563-e6601100-47aa-11eb-8baf-dee00d8e2cd4.png 
check lifecycle diagram provided by your lib.

Comment: I tried as you said in your first comment but it didn't change the result. I am struggling it's lifecycle and how to use it. May be an example could help me in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Try below codde hope its helpful to you. Use **`assets_audio_player`** package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player)

your function:

```
  playSound() async { 
    AssetsAudioPlayer audioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer();
    await audioPlayer.open(
      Audio(
        'assets/bells.mp3',
      ),
    );
  }
```

Your Widget:

```
   ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () => playSound(),
        child: Text(
          'Play',
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: I tried assets_audio_player too. But it didn't work. Also it is not compatible with Windows platform. Did you check it in Windows?

Comment: Yes, Its working on both Mac and Widows

Comment: I Added **assets_audio_player: ^3.0.3+9**  in pubspec.yaml file and facing the following errors-

`flutter: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method stop on channel assets_audio_player)`

`flutter: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method open on channel assets_audio_player)`

`[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method open on channel assets_audio_player)`.

Comment: Stop and relaunch your app and then check your output

Comment: I searched in the google and already tried this and got the same result.

Comment: But this is perfect work on my machine, are you set the correct path of assets in `pubspeac.yaml` file?

Comment: Yes!!! When I used just_audio, the audio was loaded from that path.